# BERT error - module 'tensorflow_core.keras.activations' has no attribute 'swish'

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am trying to execute the transformer model but ended up with error.

- Python version == 3.7
- Tensorflow     == 2.0
- Transformers   == 4.15.0

Source : https://huggingface.co/cross-encoder/nli-deberta-base?candidateLabels=supply+chain%2C+scientific+discovery%2C+microbiology%2C+robots%2C+archeology&multiClass=false&text=shipment+will+arrive+on+next+week.+our+company+will+transport

my code:

```
import tensorflow
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForTokenClassification,BertTokenizer
pipeline("zero-shot-classification",model="cross-encoder/nli-deberta-v3-small")
```

Error : module 'tensorflow_core.keras.activations' has no attribute 'swish'

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Tensorflow==2.3 and restarted the machine. Now the error gone....